# I've fixed this question. Is it good enough?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question

In https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16128831/something-turn-on-gps-but-what-how-do-i-find-which-object-uses-gps I basically ask if there is a debugging technique that allow us to know which objects use location update.

Now we know that something is using location update when an arrow shows up on status bar. But which ones? an MKMapview, a CLLocationManager? What?

Is there a tool to find out?

Comment: I didn't know Wing Wing was a coder.

Comment: who is wing wing?

Comment: Your avatar is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's certainly a lot better; you're now asking *for* something. You edited it, and it went into the [re-open queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/1964207) where 3 people voted to reopen the question.

I've cleaned up the grammar slightly and removed *"Is there a tool to find out?"*, which makes it sound like a shopping question.

You now have 4 reopen votes so only require one more (which has now happened).

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I think many people must have the same problem as I do.